# How can I cancel a hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

If a user presses the "search" button and then they decide to do "something else", we have to cancel an already running query.

We use Hibernate (and Oracle) as persistence solution. Hibernates Session interface provides a `cancelQuery()` method. After some testing, it seems that `cancelQuery()` has no effect.

Does anybody have some experience with this `Session#cancelQuery()` method?

Thank you!

Comment: I found the the cancelQuery method only works while the application is waiting for the database to start returning results. However, once Hibernate has received a result set from the database and starts mapping the results to the objects then it already has no effect, and this is really where the bulk of the performance overhead is. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391785/outofmemoryerror-as-a-result-of-multiple-searches

Answer (score 7):

It has an effect but with the Oracle JDBC driver, it just takes some time to happen. Just wait a minute or two.

If you can't wait, then move the cancel in a background thread (along with the session) and request a new Hibernate session in your main thread. You can't use the old session until `cancelQuery()` returns.