# OutOfMemoryError as a result of multiple searches

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, db2, out-of-memory

I have a classic Java EE system, Web tier with JSF, EJB 3 for the BL, and Hibernate 3 doing the data access to a DB2 database. I am struggling with the following scenario: A user will initiate a process which involves retrieving a large data set from the database. The retrieval process takes some time and so the user does not receive an immediate response, gets impatient and opens a new browser and initiates the retrieval again, sometimes multiple times. The EJB container is obviously unaware of the fact that the first retrievals are no longer relevant, and when the database returns a result set, Hibernate starts populating a set of POJOs which take up vast amounts of memory, eventually causing an `OutOfMemoryError`.

A potential solution that I thought of was to use the Hibernate Session's `cancelQuery` method. However, the `cancelQuery` method only works **before** the database returns a result set. Once the database returns a result set and Hibernate begins populating the POJOs, the `cancelQuery` method no longer has an effect. In this case, the database queries themselves return rather quickly, and the bulk of the performance overhead seems to reside in populating the POJOs, at which point we can no longer call the `cancelQuery` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution implemented ended up looking like this:

The general idea was to maintain a map of all the Hibernate sessions that are currently running queries to the HttpSession of the user who initiated them, so that when the user would close the browser we would be able to kill the running queries.

There were two main challenges to overcome here. One was propagating the HTTP session-id from the web tier to the EJB tier without interfering with all the method calls along the way - i.e. not tampering with existing code in the system. The second challenge was to figure out how to cancel the queries once the database had already started returning results and Hibernate was populating objects with the results.

The first problem was overcome based on our realization that all methods being called along the stack were being handled by the same thread. This makes sense, as our application exists all within one container and [does not have any remote calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328626/2992404). Being that that is the case, we created a Servlet Filter that intercepts every call to the application and adds a `ThreadLocal` variable with the current HTTP session-id. This way the HTTP session-id will be available to each one of the method calls lower down along the line.

The second challenge was a little more sticky. We discovered that the Hibernate method responsible for running the queries and subsequently populating the POJOs was called `doQuery` and located in the `org.hibernate.loader.Loader.java` class. (We happen to be using Hibernate 3.5.3, but the same holds true for newer versions of Hibernate.):

```
private List doQuery(
        final SessionImplementor session,
        final QueryParameters queryParameters,
        final boolean returnProxies) throws SQLException, HibernateException {

    final RowSelection selection = queryParameters.getRowSelection();
    final int maxRows = hasMaxRows( selection ) ?
            selection.getMaxRows().intValue() :
            Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    final int entitySpan = getEntityPersisters().length;

    final ArrayList hydratedObjects = entitySpan == 0 ? null : new ArrayList( entitySpan * 10 );
    final PreparedStatement st = prepareQueryStatement( queryParameters, false, session );
    final ResultSet rs = getResultSet( st, queryParameters.hasAutoDiscoverScalarTypes(), queryParameters.isCallable(), selection, session );

    final EntityKey optionalObjectKey = getOptionalObjectKey( queryParameters, session );
    final LockMode[] lockModesArray = getLockModes( queryParameters.getLockOptions() );
    final boolean createSubselects = isSubselectLoadingEnabled();
    final List subselectResultKeys = createSubselects ? new ArrayList() : null;
    final List results = new ArrayList();

    try {

        handleEmptyCollections( queryParameters.getCollectionKeys(), rs, session );

        EntityKey[] keys = new EntityKey[entitySpan]; //we can reuse it for each row

        if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) log.trace( "processing result set" );

        int count;
        for ( count = 0; count < maxRows && rs.next(); count++ ) {

            if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) log.debug("result set row: " + count);

            Object result = getRowFromResultSet( 
                    rs,
                    session,
                    queryParameters,
                    lockModesArray,
                    optionalObjectKey,
                    hydratedObjects,
                    keys,
                    returnProxies 
            );
            results.add( result );

            if ( createSubselects ) {
                subselectResultKeys.add(keys);
                keys = new EntityKey[entitySpan]; //can't reuse in this case
            }

        }

        if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) {
            log.trace( "done processing result set (" + count + " rows)" );
        }

    }
    finally {
        session.getBatcher().closeQueryStatement( st, rs );
    }

    initializeEntitiesAndCollections( hydratedObjects, rs, session, queryParameters.isReadOnly( session ) );

    if ( createSubselects ) createSubselects( subselectResultKeys, queryParameters, session );

    return results; //getResultList(results);

}
```

In this method you can see that first the results are brought from the database in the form of a good old fashioned `java.sql.ResultSet`, after which it runs in a loop over each set and creates an object from it. Some additional initialization is performed in the `initializeEntitiesAndCollections()` method called after the loop. After debugging a little, we discovered that the bulk of the performance overhead was in these sections of the method, and not in the part that gets the `java.sql.ResultSet` from the database, but the `cancelQuery` method was only effective on the first part. The solution therefore was to add an additional condition to the for loop, to check whether the thread is interrupted like this:

```
for ( count = 0; count < maxRows && rs.next() && !currentThread.isInterrupted(); count++ ) {
// ...
}
```

as well as to perform the same check before calling the `initializeEntitiesAndCollections()` method:

```
if (!Thread.interrupted()) {

    initializeEntitiesAndCollections(hydratedObjects, rs, session,
                queryParameters.isReadOnly(session));
    if (createSubselects) {

        createSubselects(subselectResultKeys, queryParameters, session);
    }
}
```

Additionally, by calling the `Thread.interrupted()` on the second check, the flag is cleared and does not affect the further functioning of the program. Now when a query is to be canceled, the canceling method accesses the Hibernate session and thread stored in a map with the HTTP session-id as the key, calls the `cancelQuery` method on the session and calls the `interrupt` method of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem in a totally different environment. I did the following: before adding the new job to my queue I first checked whether the 'same job' is already enqueued from that user. If so I do not accept the second job and inform the user about that.

This doesn't answer your question on how to protect the user from an outOfMemory if the data is too big to fit in the available ram. But it's a good trick to protect your server from doing useless stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated for me :-) I would like to create separate service for "heavy" queries. And store in it information about query parameters, maybe results, which would be valid limited time. If query execution is too long, user receive message, that execution of his task will takes considerable time, and he may wait or cancel it.  Such scenario works fine for analytic queries. This variant gave you simple access to task, running on the server, to kill its.

But if you has problem with hibernate, than I suppose that problem not in analytic queries, but in ordinary business queries. If its execution too long, can you try to use L2 cache (cold start may be very long, but hot data would be received instantly)? Or optimize hibernate\jbdc parameters?