# Abort or terminate the Request which takes long time to respond back

Tags: web-services, jpa, jax-rs, ejb-3.0, smartgwt

I have an application developed using `SmartGWT,Jaxrs,ejb &jpa`.

- I have one scenario where user wants to extract the data(called Search Screen) by entering either firstname,lastname or middlebane,ssn,email,etc
- Database contains the huge number of records in millions, which takes lot of time to respond back.
- for example, user search with firstname which takes lot of time to respond, in that case user wants to `cancel/terminate/abort` the request.
- Is it possible either in smartgwt or jaxrs(web api) to terminate the request.
  So that user can terminate the request and move further

PS:: i tried lot of option,but i didn't get the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the business logic in stateful bean and put the bean in the http session ... now you have access to the currently used persistence context and the open transaction so you can call `Session.cancelQuery()` .... but this method has some limitation .. It works only if Result set is not yet returned , if this limitation harms you, check [this answer please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391785/outofmemoryerror-as-a-result-of-multiple-searches)

There are other workarounds to synchronize the web client with the business method but this is the one I like most

One more thing you need to consider as this is your use case is to introduce a new lexical search engine like solr or elasticsearch which can be updated frequently with data from the database ... It fits perfectly in lexical search, gives the ability to stand typo mistakes and returns result very quickly

Comment: Thanks osama for your response..i already tried adding this into thread and terminating but it doesn't work..again implementing elasticsearch is not so easy..any other way

Comment: welcome bro ... you tried it with the persistence context still open ?